# Need to submit twice my form (something wrong with my tiny_mce plugin)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use a tiny_mce plugin to have a textarea with advanced editing (bold, italic, ...) see below. The attribute behind this textarea is required (validation).

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Project.Content, new { style = "height:250px;width:100%;", @class = "mceEditor" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Project.Content)
```

In my model, I defined the attribute as required.

```
    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }
```

The problem is that when I submit my form for the first time, I have a validation error on this control (even if something is typed in it). The second time the form is submitted I don't have any validation error.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, It's basically a bug in Asp.net MVC3 due to which the unobtrusive validations don't work for nested properties in TextAreaFor. You can read further at [codeplex workitem](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8576).

I would suggest you to use the Editorfor in it's place and decorate the respective property with following code :-

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[Required]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately the tiny mce editor doesn't seems to work with an EditorFor in place of a TextAreaFor. I tried it but I doesn't see any tiny_mce toolbar.

Comment: I find it strange...Did u decorate your property with the `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` ... A property such as this yields textarea only when used for Editor for

Comment: I try both (TextBoxFor and EditorFor) without success. I also decorated the property. It seems we MUST use the TextAreaFor with tinymce.

Comment: Sorry I don't have experience of working with tiny mce. Hope other users provide an answer. In the meantime, I will read more into the tiny mce and will reply once I have a concrete solution....